# Move Cursor Up/Down Lines

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to mimic the functionality I set in Sublime Text that allows me to move the cursor much like 'j' or 'k' in VI. In the Windows world I guess it would be similar to a pgup/pgdn, however I'd like to just go up/down one line not one page.
Here's my bindings in Sublime Text that I'd like to mimic:

```
[
   {"keys": ["ctrl+i"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": false}},
   { "keys": ["ctrl+k"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": true}}
]
```

Edit: As Logarr pointed out, the easier way to phrase this is I want to mimic the Up/Down arrow keys using ctrl+i and ctrl+k

Comment: I've never been a fan of VI, but I'm assuming you mean you want the page to scroll one line at a time. Is that correct? **EDIT:** I just launched VI, and the functionality of `j` and `k` is just the same as using the up/down arrows...

Comment: Yep, I guess I could have just said mimic the up/down arrow keys... Now I feel foolish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are already Vim extensions for Visual Studio.  There is the free [VsVim](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329) extension that works in Visual Studio 2010+ and [ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com/) which works in Visual Studio 2003+ plus a few other applications.

If you just want to remap the up and down keys, then you can change the keyboard mapping.  From Tools->Options find the Keyboard section.  From there you can change the key bindings for `Edit.LineDown` and `Edit.LineUp`.   You may want to select the Text Editor for the "Use new shortcut in:" setting so these changes only affect the text editor.

Comment: I'm really only trying to enable those two actions; I didn't want to jump in with a full on Vi extension because I'm not very adept at it

Answer (score 1):

This would have been trivial if Microsoft hadn't ripped the macro functionality out of Visual Studio.

You could install [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and write a simple script. This would have the advantage that you could apply these keymappings to any applications you like as well as Visual Studio.